# Не могу достать объект из списка

Tags: scala, playframework

Нужно достать объект `User` из структуры:

```
List(Map(
   name -> ArrayBuffer(), 
   age -> ArrayBuffer(), 
   deleteItem -> ArrayBuffer(User(1,Nick Holland,25,None)), 
   action -> ArrayBuffer(remove)))
```

Код:

```
val a = request.body.asFormUrlEncoded.toSeq.map(a => a.map(b => b))
```

Comment: Зачем нужен `map(b => b)`? Это бессмысленно, и вернет тот же объект. А потому бессмысленно   отображение `map(a => a.map(b => b))`.
Хотя вообще говоря, весь "код" бессмысленен, т.к. непонятно, как он соотносится со "структурой"

Answer (score 0):

Для одного значения Map в List:

```
val a = l match {
  case List(m) => m("deleteItem")(0)
}
```

Для нескольких значений Map в List будет тип List[User]:

```
val a = l.map( m => m("deleteItem")(0))
```